# How do I design a collection with graph database?

Tags: database-design, neo4j, architecture, orientdb, graph-databases

I am trying to design a collection system with graph database. A user can create multiple collections of posts. I can't decide which of the two given designs is scalable and good.

So here is the **the first design,**

> The **User** node (vertex) is related to **Collection** node (vertex) with relation (edge) **`HAS_COLLECTION`**

[image]

and **the second design**,

> The **User** node (vertex) is related to **Collections** node (vertex) and the **Collection** node (vertex) is related to **Collections** node (vertex) with relation (edge) **`HAS_COLLECTION`**

[image]

So my questions are,

1. Which of the two design is good and scalable?
2. Why should I opt one over another?
3. What relation verbs can be used in specific scenario instead of the ones in the design?

Comment: how many collections will be per user ?

Comment: @TomažBratanič there may be one `Collections` and n `collection` per user

Answer (score 3):

1 & 2: Unless you have specific reasons for needing the `CREATED` relationship and the `Collections` node, you should omit them. In general, keeping your paths shorter is better, since your queries would be simpler and faster, and require less storage.

3: Names are something of a personal preference, but to me `HAS_POST` would be clearer than `COLLECTED`.

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2 depends on use case i.e if the group of collection actually exist go with (2) otherwise (1)

Ex- If the user maintains group of collections then I would prefer (2). Ex- If a user has started collecting post for sports, astronomy, science and technology, politics, movies. It makes sense to go with (2) design. The search query for "post" is going to quicker (By just putting say "sports" it will filter out all the non-sports post.